# Creating a automated function with tidyverse that merges two datasets taken from a list of list in R that gives the merged dataset

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I want to create a function that merges two datasets taken from the same list (which is a list of list) that contains several objects for each list. Will, however simplify my code for the sake of readability. Thus, my example is just a snippet of the entire objects I have in this list of list.

I am attempting to automatise my analysis and ease my work. Thus, creating functions are necessary. If possible to achieve this with tidyverse that would be awesome. This is my background and problem at hand I am working on.

Anyways this is the example of the list I have:

```
list(dataset1: list of 2:
            ..data: 
       config_path: chr "config_direct/dataset1/"
     dataset2: list of 2:
            ..data: Classes                         
       config_path: chr "config_direct/dataset2/")
```

Which is formed based on the bellow tibbles

```
ID <- c(101, 102, 2013)
Name <- c("Chris", "Mary", "Ana")
salary <- c(100, 200, 300)

dataset1 <- tibble::tibble(ID, Name, salary)

ID <- c(104, 105, 106)
Name <- c("John", "Christine", "Thomas")
salary <- c(150, 250, 330)
```

And this is the function I have attempted

```
 merging_datasets <- function(data_standardised = the_list_of_list, 
                              first_data = first_object_in_list, 
                              second_data = second_object_in_list, 
                              merged_data = TRUE) {


      if(merged_data == TRUE){

        first_data <- data_standardised$first_in_list[[1]]
        second_data <- data_standardised$second_in_list[[1]]

        merged_data <- merge(first_data, second_data)

      }else{

        NULL

      }

    }
```

with the merged dataset output of zero values when applied the function:

```
merged_dfs <-  merging_datasets(data_standardised = data_standard, first_data = dataset1, second_data = dataset2, merged_data = TRUE)
```

Can someone help me with this. Again, this is for the automation purposes, thus the obvious questions as to why you do not use the merge function already given does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the function to

```
 merging_datasets <- function(data_standardised = the_list_of_list, obs_names_to_merge,                               
                              merged_data = TRUE) {


      if(merged_data){

       Reduce(function(...) merge(...), data_standarised[obs_names_to_merge])



      }else{

        NULL

      }

    }
```

---

If we want to do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
data_standardised  %>%
       map(pluck, 1) %>%
       reduce(left_join)
```

Or use

```
data_standardised %>%
      map(pluck, 'data') %>%
      reduce(left_join)
```

#### data

```
data_standardised <- list(dataset1 = list(data = dataset1, config_path = 'xyz'), 
  dataset2 = list(data = dataset2, config_path = 'another xyz'))
```

Comment: thank you akrun. can you explain what Reduce does and what function(...) is? merge(...)? Because in the list I have more objects, paths, etc. Thus,  the need to retried the data is necessary.

Comment: I have changed my code with what the list contains. Hopefully your code works regardless of the changes.

Comment: yep, changed the actual list of list. Thank you a lot.

Comment: my list of list has two objects. with each object having data and a path. But want to retrieve the data only, for both objects. But not the paths as I am not interested in other stuff that it contains. Am I clear now?

Comment: I have updated the first code. It is a snipped of how the list of list looks like. I hope it is better

Comment: akrun, i have used pluck but it seems to work only as one object passed such as 'dataset1'. Is there another function to pass pluck('dataset1', dataset2', 'data') ? Or something similar?

Comment: I want to retrieve from data from each object. that means dataset1 and dataset2 with both datasets given into one if this is possible .. And do not know whether there is a function like that??

Comment: i need to be honest, do not understand. But partially I got the answer - with pluck. Will post it when I get it. Apologies.

Comment: I am simply novice at R. I would, nevertheless put upvotes. I just want to get it first and then will vote. And thank you for helping. It is really nice of you.